# Is "An arming soldier" the correct word order in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

I wrote the sentence:

> *An arming soldier* preparing against invasion of the enemy was suddenly killed when a bomb exploded in the trench.

What I want to describe is that a soldier was arming himself.

Can I phrase it as "An arming soldier"?

But in my opinion, it is very ambiguous in that it can be read either a soldier who was arming himself or a soldier who was arming another soldier.

So, I think that it would be better to write this way

> *A soldier arming himself* to prepare against invasion of the enemy was suddenly killed when a bomb exploded in the trench.

Does this rephrasing more correctly convey what I'm trying to say?

Comment: This question is specifically asking about "an arming soldier". I don't see how this is "proofreading".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a modern context, to "arm" someone means to *issue* them military equipment, and not to pick up *armaments* or put on *armor*.  A soldier should have been *armed* long before heading into battle, so in the situation you describe it would be more idiomatic to specifically describe what he was doing:

> The soldier was **readying his weapons** when he was killed by an explosion in his trench.
>
> While **loading his rifle** the soldier was killed by a mortar round.
>
> As he was **getting into his gear** (putting on his equipment -- helmet, Kevlar vest, etc.) the soldier was killed by a nearby blast.

Note that soldiers can *arm themselves* in preparation for battle, so if you are describing an attack on *unprepared* forces, then "arming" can work:

> While the soldiers were **arming themselves** the enemy attacked the camp and took them by surprise.

"Arming themselves" can also be used as a participle:

> The soldiers, **arming themselves**, were killed in a surprise attack

but again, it's more common to describe exactly what they were doing at the time -- loading weapons, getting their equipment ready, checking their communications, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways to write this sentence, but I'd like to focus on the main issues.

First of all, "an arming soldier" doesn't have the problem of being ambiguous, as you say.  Rather, it's practically ungrammatical.  It would be like describing a soldier who is currently eating as "an eating soldier".  That construction can be used to describe a *type* of thing.  So "a flying insect" is ok because it's a type of insect that flies.

In your second attempt, you're weighing down the subject by making it a long noun-phrase.  Here it is again, taken to a more obvious extreme:

- A soldier arming himself to prepare against invasion of the enemy by taking bullets and carefully putting them in his gun while thinking about his family back in his home town was suddenly killed.

A minimal fix would be to use commas:

- A soldier, arming himself to prepare against invasion of the enemy, was suddenly killed.

Other improvements would be a matter of style and writing skill.